# angular material md-option width issue with long value

Tags: angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

I am having issue with angular material `md-option` size where the value string is long, it does not obey to flex size and it causes width to break the flex size.

**HTML:**

```
<div layout="row" flex class="md-padding" ng-app="app">
  <div layout="row" flex="100">
    <div flex="35" layout="row" layout-align="start center">Group:</div>
    <div flex="65" layout-align="start center">
      <md-select ng-model="SelectedGroup">
        <md-option value="Group 1">
          Group 1
        </md-option>
        <md-option value="Group 2">
          Group 2 has long text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim distinctio possimus corporis dolores ad obcaecati incidunt quia dolore, nesciunt praesentium provident suscipit amet, dignissimos natus repellat voluptatibus facilis molestiae quos.
        </md-option>
      </md-select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div flex="5"></div>
  <div layout="row" flex="100">
    <div flex="35" layout="row" layout-align="start center">
      Item:
    </div>
    <div flex="65" layout="row" layout-align="start center">
      <md-select ng-model="SelectedItem">
        <md-option ng-value="Item1">
          Item 1
        </md-option>
      </md-select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Issue on codepen](http://codepen.io/MoAsmar/pen/apxBNQ)

Comment: So do you expect 2 rows for longer names or what?

Comment: the issue is not in the white-space or word-break, text should be wrapped in the selected flex size exp: flex="65" but it pushes the next element to right to take more width.
(ellipis text by default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very Simple mistake. The sum of the flex for each div should be 100. In your case its `100+5+100`. Just make it as `40+10+40` and it will work.
Here is the Code.

```
<div layout="row" flex class="md-padding" ng-app="app">
 <div layout="row" flex="40">
  <div flex="35" layout="row" layout-align="start center">Group:</div>
  <div flex="65">
   <md-select ng-model="SelectedGroup">
    <md-option value="Group 1">
      Group 1
    </md-option>
    <md-option value="Group 2">
      Group 2 has long text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim distinctio possimus corporis dolores ad obcaecati incidunt quia dolore, nesciunt praesentium provident suscipit amet, dignissimos natus repellat voluptatibus facilis
      molestiae quos.
    </md-option>
  </md-select>
 </div>
</div>
 <div flex="10"></div>
 <div layout="row" flex="40">
  <div flex="35" layout="row" layout-align="start center">
   Item:
  </div>
  <div flex="65" layout="row" layout-align="start center">
   <md-select ng-model="SelectedItem">
    <md-option ng-value="Item1">
      Item 1
    </md-option>
   </md-select>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is the working [Codepen](http://codepen.io/next1/pen/apxGXY).

Comment: Thank you, the same solution I applied with help of a friend.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in order to get the md-options to properly trim & ... very long option labels, I had to:

set `layout="none center"`  (added the none)

to an outer div that wraps the `<md-select>`

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="none center">
    <md-select aria-label="Please select an option">
        <md-option ng-repeat="eachOption in myModel.Values" ng-value="eachOption">
            {{eachOption.name}}
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
</div>
```